# Import from IBM Rational Clearcase to TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, clearcase

I need to migrate from Clearcase to TFS 2013, I have searched for a solution that helps me and I found the [TFS Integration tool](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) at CodePlex, but it does not seems to work with TFS 2013. So, does anyone has had need to do this and found a solution?

When I try to install the TFS integration tool in a server with TFS 2013 this error is displayed:

[image]

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/07/27/getting-started-with-ibm-rational-to-team-foundation-server-tfs-migrations.aspx refers indeed to TFS2011, but I don't see any reason for those same tools to not work with TFS2013. I don't have direct experience in that process. Did you try it?

Comment: As you can see @VonC I updated my question with an image of the error that is displayed when trying to use it.

Comment: Have you installed Team Explorer or Visual Studio on the machine you are running it on?

Comment: @yosoy I have added a link describing the error message you see as well as a possible workaround.

Comment: Yes @DaveShaw the Team Explorer is installed.

Answer (score 0):

The process described in "[Getting Started with IBM Rational to Team Foundation Server (TFS) Migrations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/07/27/getting-started-with-ibm-rational-to-team-foundation-server-tfs-migrations.aspx)" should work with more recent TFS version (2012, 2à13)

The error message "This tool requires the TFS client object model" can be seen in those recent versions: see "[TFS Integration Tools – Issue: “This tool requires the TFS client object model”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2012/07/04/tfs-integration-tools-issue-this-tool-requires-the-tfs-client-object-model.aspx)".

> When installing the TFS Integration Tools on **a machine that only has the Team Explorer installed, the installation fails** with the error

```
This tool requires the TFS client object model.
```

Comment: Sorry @VonC, I can't see either of the links you post in the answer. Can you check them please? In the other hand, I have installed the TFS 2013 and the Team Explorer in the machine where I'm trying to install the tool. Is the TFS client object model an additional installation?

Comment: @yosoy the link is http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2012/07/04/tfs-integration-tools-issue-this-tool-requires-the-tfs-client-object-model.aspx

Comment: Thanks @VonC, let me check it.

Comment: Well, I tried all options that are given there and no one worked for TFS 2013. Thanks for trying.